# Automapper как унаследовать конфигурацию родителя?

Tags: c#, .net, классы, .net-core, automapper

Есть два родительских объекта **A** и **B** типа `Parent`. У объекта **A** некоторые поля типа `Child` у которых есть nullable поля и они равны `null`.

```cs
enum Gender {
    Male = 1,
    Female
}

class Parent {
    public int Number;
    public Child Children;
}

class Child {
    public string Name;
    public Gender? Gender; 
}

/// Объект A
var a = new Parent {
    Number = 1,
    Children = new Child {
        Name = "Child2",
        Gender = null // <---------------------------
    }
};
```

И есть объект **B** с которым надо слить **A** и у которого поле `Gender` не равно `null` тоесть его надо оставить не тронутым:

```cs
/// Объект B
var b = new Parent {
    Number = 2,
    Children = new Child {
        Name = "Child1",
        Gender = Gender.Male // При слиянии не трогать если у объекта A там null
    }
};
```

Необходимо делать слияние двух родительских объектов **A** и **B**, но если поля у объекта **A** или у его потомков равны `null`, то у объекта **B** оставлять значения полей не тронутыми(не перетирать их `null`’ами)

Настраивая AutoMapper, я указал опцию:

```cs
CreateMap<Parent, Parent>().ForAllMembers(options =>
    options.UseDestinationValue()
);
```

Она решает проблему для объектов `Parent`, но не для объектов `Child`, что бы работало и для `Child`, необходимо настраивать еще и для них так же:

```cs
CreateMap<Child, Child>().ForAllMembers(options =>
    options.UseDestinationValue()
);
```

**Вопрос** в том, можно ли избежать дополнительных настроек, задав один раз для всех объектов которые содержит в себе `Parent` потому что в реальной жизни придётся писать несколько десятков таких настроек для всех типов которые содержатся в родительских классах, а это могут быть сотни.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем AutoMapper не работает как задумано и смёрджить два объекта используя его не выходит. В итоге я написал вот такой экстеншн который решил все проблемы.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
public static class MergeExt {
    public static T Merge<T>(this T source, T dest) {
        var jsource = JObject.FromObject(source);
        var jdest = JObject.FromObject(dest);

        jdest.Merge(jsource, new JsonMergeSettings {
            MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Replace
        });

        return jdest.ToObject<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как я не дождался ответа на свой вопрос пришлось написать такой велосипед(пример приведен для класса у которого все члены свойства так как это покрывает мой конкретный случай):

```cs
private void InitMapper() {
    var types = GetTypes(typeof(Parent));

    foreach (var type in types) {
        CreateMap(type, type).ForAllMembers(options =>
            options.UseDestinationValue()
        );
    }
}

private static List<Type> GetTypes(Type type) {
    var list = new List<Type> {
        type
    };

    var props = type.GetProperties();

    foreach (var item in props) {
        var currentType = item.PropertyType.IsArray 
            ? item.PropertyType.GetElementType()
            : item.PropertyType;

        if (currentType.IsPrimitive == false 
            && currentType.IsClass 
            && currentType != typeof(String)) {

            list.AddRange(GetTypes(currentType));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```